# Калькулятор с ползунком (фейдером) на JS/jQuery. Как сделать, что бы при движении ползунка значение менялось везде?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

var rangeValue = function(){
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var target = document.querySelector('.value');
  target.innerHTML = newValue;
}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

```css
.first__section {
  padding-top: 65px;
  background-color: #8de482;
}

.first__section .container {
  padding: 20px 12px;
}

.first__section .container .first__section-txt {
  font-family: "Marvin", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.first__section .container .first__section-img {
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 300px;
}

.first__section .container .section__title {
  color: #00719e;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.first__section .container .value {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 85px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #00acc4;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.first__section .container .age {
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 240px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.first__section .container input[type="range"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #ca94b3;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  border-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 0;
}

.first__section .container input[type="range"]::before, .first__section .container input[type="range"]::after {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

.first__section .container input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 8px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.counter__value {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.counter__value .container .wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.counter__value .container .product {
  background-color: #ca94b3;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.counter__value .container .product img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 35px auto;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(8px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
          filter: drop-shadow(8px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.counter__value .container .tab {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #00acc4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.counter__value .container .tab .value {
  border: 2px dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  margin: 7px 10px;
}

.counter__value .container .value__wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.counter__value .container .value__wrapper .tab__item {
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.counter__value .container .value__wrapper .tab__item .valeu__subname {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.counter__value .container .btn {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #00acc4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="first__section">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="section__title">калькулятор годування</h1>
        <div class="counter" id="counter">
            <div class="value">0</div>
            <div class="age"> <span>0 днiв</span> <span>6 мiс.</span> <span>12 мiс.</span> </div>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="12" step="1" value="0" id="fader"> </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="counter__value">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="tabs">
                <div class="tab">
                    <h3 class="value__name">Вік дитини</h3>
                    <div class="value" id="years">1 тиждень</div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab">
                    <h3 class="value__name">Кількість годувань на добу</h3>
                    <div class="value" id="feedings">8</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <h3 class="value__name">Кількість на одне годування</h3>
            <div class="value__wrapper">
                <div class="tab__item">
                    <h4 class="valeu__subname">Прокип’ячена вода <br> мл</h4>
                    <div class="value" id="water">60</div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab__item">
                    <h4 class="valeu__subname">Кількість мірних ложок порошку</h4>
                    <div class="value" id="spoons">2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <a href="#" class="btn">купити</a> </div>
</section>
```

[image: Скриншот интерфейса]

Answer (score 1):

```
let elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
let age = document.querySelector('#years');
let feed = document.querySelector('#feedings');
let water = document.querySelector('#water');
let spoons = document.querySelector('#spoons');

const rangeValue = function(){
  let newValue = elem.value;
  
  //вычисления необходимых параметров на основании newValue   
  ...

  //запись полученых значений в дивы
  age.textContent = ...;
  water.textContent = ...;
  feed.textContent = ...;
  spoons.textContent = ...;  
}

elem.addEventListener("change", rangeValue);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но каждое окошко показывает разные значения, и для них у меня прописаны id, и как это все собрать в одно я без понятия. Может это всё можно сделать через if? Ведь значения по факту статичные, и на каждом отрезке будет показываться только один вариант

Comment: Изначальный вопрос был в другом. Если вам нужно, чтобы от изменения одного инпута производились вычисления в нужных вам дивах, значит делайте необхоимую калькуляцию в функции и выводите каждое значение в конкретный div через querySelector('#id'). И да, можно через If